# React not initialising state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While following the basic react tutorial at
https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html,

I ran into the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of null`

After some debugging, localised the error to `state` not being accessible from other methods.

In index.js

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        var state = {
            history: [
                {
                    squares: Array(9).fill(null)
                }
            ],
            xIsNext: true
        };
    }
    ...
```

```
    render() {
        const history = this.state.history; //Error thrown here
        const current = history[history.length - 1];
        const winner = this.calculateWinner(current.squares);
        let status;
        ...
```

Comment: Replace `var state =` with `this.state =`

Answer (score 1):

The issue arises from the constructor where state is initialised.

replace

```
        var state = {
            history: [
                {
                    squares: Array(9).fill(null)
                }
            ],
            xIsNext: true
        };
```

with

```
        this.state = {
            history: [
                {
                    squares: Array(9).fill(null)
                }
            ],
            xIsNext: true
        };
```